# Given the following inequality $x>\ln{1+x}$, make implications

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

$x-\ln{(1+x)} > 0 \ \ \forall \  x : x > 0$ basically I showed this. And then I try to apply this idea to the following $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} > \ln(n+1)$.

Applying the idea of that initial example:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} > \ln(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} +1)$$

I however fail to see how $$\ln(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} +1) \equiv \sum_{k=1}^n \ln(\frac{1}{k}+1)$$ which is a key to solving the problem.

Comment: Try using the inequality term by term ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k>\sum_{k=1}^n\ln(1+\tfrac 1k)= \sum_{k=1}^n\left(\ln(k+1)-\ln(k)\right)=\ln(n+1)-\ln(1)$$

Comment: but that is precisely my question... why is $\sum_{k=1}^n \ln{(\frac{1}{k}+1)} \leq \ln{(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} +1)}$

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal that is not being used at all. what is used is $\frac1k>\ln(1+\frac1k)$. Sum that and you get the first step.

Comment: @Macavity that is not trivial to me either, why is $1/k > \ln(1+1/k)$? Sorry

Comment: That is your "given" inequality, with $x=\frac1k$. Showing why that holds is a different though simple exercise, and I am sure already done many times at this site.

Comment: Oh I have done that proof. Sorry, I forgot it was my initial inequality.. oh dear